# Dictionary, multidimensional or jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have this string:

```
string Text = "{1}[56](17)(20)(13)(14)[895](11)(20)[3](8)(12)(3)[19](1)(2)(13)(7)(6)";
```

and i have to return this:

```
   Array (  [Type] => 1
             [Items] => Array ( [56] => Array (  [1] => 17
                                                 [2] => 20
                                                 [3] => 13
                                                 [4] => 14 )
                                [895] => Array (  [1] => 11
                                                  [2] => 20 )
                                [3] => Array (  [1] => 8
                                                [2] => 12
                                                [3] => 3 )
                                [19] => Array (  [1] => 1
                                                 [2] => 2
                                                 [3] => 13
                                                 [4] => 7
                                                 [5] => 6 )
                                )
        )
```

How can i make this? I succeded in php but in c# i can't find the solution. I've tried first with dictionary, but i just can't reach it. I just don't know how to make a dictionary with a key with multiple values witch also have multiple values. So far i did this:

```
    var Menu_Matrix = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var Menu_Items = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    char[] sep1 = { '{', '}' };
    char[] sep2 = { '[', ']' };
    char[] sep3 = { '(', ')' };
    string[] Menu_Id = new string [10];
    string[] Category_Id = new string[20];
    Menu_Id = Text.Split(sep1);
    Menu_Matrix.Add("Type", Menu_Id[1]);
    Category_Id = Menu_Id[2].Split(sep2);
    int cat_len = 0;
    cat_len = Category_Id.Length;
    for (int i = 1; i < cat_len;i++)
     { int pos = 0;
       if(Category_Id[i+1].IndexOf('(')!=-1)
         pos=i+1;
       if(pos>i)
        { var item = new List<string>();
          string[] Item_id = new string[20];
          Item_id = Category_Id[pos].Split(sep3);
          for (int j = 1; j < Item_id.Length;j++ )
             if(Item_id[j]!="")
                 item.Add(Item_id[j]);
          Menu_Items.Add(Category_Id[i], item);
         }
     i = pos;
       }
     }
     return Menu_Items;
```

and the result is:

```
                             [56] => Array ( [1] => 17
                                             [2] => 20
                                             [3] => 13
                                             [4] => 14 )
                             [895] => Array ( [1] => 11
                                              [2] => 20 )
                                [3] => Array ( [1] => 8
                                               [2] => 12
                                               [3] => 3 )
                                [19] => Array ( [1] => 1
                                                [2] => 2
                                                [3] => 13
                                                [4] => 7
                                                [5] => 6 )
```

Hope you know what i wanna say and help me please! I don't care what i use : dictionary, jagged array or multidimensional array .

Comment: You said you tried something in PHP, maybe show us that so we can help you with it?

Comment: To make multiple values of same key fit into dictionary use Dictionary<key, List<values>>

Comment: Can you share what do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Ok. This is my code in php which returns my matrix like i want it.

Comment: the result look like this:   Array (  [Type] => 1
             [Items] => Array ( [56] => Array (  [1] => 17
                                                 [2] => 20
                                                 [3] => 13
                                                 [4] => 14 )
                                [895] => Array (  [1] => 11
                                                  [2] => 20 )
                                [3] => Array (  [1] => 8
                                                [2] => 12
                                                [3] => 3 ) etc,
        )

Comment: i already use dictionary, but my problem is : i have two keys (Type and Items), where Type has just one value, but key Items has multiple values, which also becomes keys with multiple values. How i make this?

Comment: Are you looking for a Dictionary of Lists (ala `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`)?

Comment: Don't put the php code in the comments, please edit your question and add it to the bottom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>` would be a good structure to store this information in.

The key to the outer Dictionary would be the values of "{#}"

The key to the inner Dictionary would be the values of "[#]"

The values in the `List`, in the inner `Dictionary`, would be the values of "(#)", but without the parentheses

To parse out this information, I thought a combinations of `Regex.Split`s to get the outer and inner keys along with a `Regex.Match` to get the values of the inner keys was a good approach.

Code Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string Text = "{1}[56](17)(20)(13)(14)[895](11)(20)[3](8)(12)(3)[19](1)(2)(13)(7)(6){2}[99](1)(2)(3)";

        // Split out pairs
        // 0: {#}
        // 1: [#](#)..(n)
        string[] splits = Regex.Split(Text, "({\\d+})").Where(split => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(split)).ToArray();
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>> items = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i += 2)
        {
            // splits[i] is {#} which will make the key for this part of the Dictionary
            items.Add(splits[i], new Dictionary<string, List<int>>());
            items[splits[i]] = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

            // Split out sub pairs
            // 0: [#]
            // 1: (#)..(n)
            string[] subSplits = Regex.Split(splits[i + 1], "(\\[\\d+\\])").Where(subSplit => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(subSplit)).ToArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < subSplits.Length; j += 2)
            {
                // subSplits[j] is [#] which will make the key for the inner Dictionary
                items[splits[i]].Add(subSplits[j], new List<int>());

                // subSplits[j + 1] is all of the (#) for each [#]
                //  which we'll add to the List of the inner Dictionary
                Match m = Regex.Match(subSplits[j + 1], "(\\d+)");
                while (m.Success)
                {
                    items[splits[i]][subSplits[j]].Add(Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[0].ToString()));
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the keys of the Dictionary, the keys of the inner Dictionary, the values of the inner Dictionary
        foreach (string key in items.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", key);
            foreach (string subKey in items[key].Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t SubKey: {0}", subKey);
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t Value: {0}", String.Join(", ", items[key][subKey]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Key: {1}
     SubKey: [56]
         Value: 17, 20, 13, 14
     SubKey: [895]
         Value: 11, 20
     SubKey: [3]
         Value: 8, 12, 3
     SubKey: [19]
         Value: 1, 2, 13, 7, 6
Key: {2}
     SubKey: [99]
         Value: 1, 2, 3
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zt5gXc

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Your solution works well but it doesn't handle exceptions. I don't know why i didn't thought at dictionary in dictionary. So i modified my code with your ideea and it works!!! Thanks again.

Comment: @NicoletaSerban What exceptions do you want it to handle? Any parsing algorithm is going to rely on the data be in the proper format.

Comment: @NicoletaSerban You mention that your code is working, if you found my answer helpful to your issue kindly click the check mark to my answer so you question is solved :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that using two RegEx Splits and a RegEx Match when you can just do single string-based split increases complexity and lowers performance. The more flat structure I used in my answer is simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider something like this:

```
string text = "{1}[56](17)(20)(13)(14)[895](11)(20)[3](8)(12)(3)[19](1)(2)(13)(7)(6)";
string[] tokens = text.Split(new Char[] { '}', ']', ')' });

char symbol;
int value;

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>> data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<int>>>();
Dictionary<int, List<int>> items = null;
List<int> leaves = null;

foreach (string token in tokens) {
   if (token.Length == 0) break;
   symbol = token[0];
   value = Int32.Parse(token.Substring(1));
   switch (symbol) {
   case '{':
     items = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
     data.Add(value, items);
     break;
   case '[':
     leaves = new List<int>();
     items.Add(value, leaves);
     break;
   case '(':
     leaves.Add(value);
     break;
   }
}

foreach (int type in data.Keys)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Type => {{{0}}}", type);
   Console.WriteLine("\tItems =>");
   items = data[type];
      foreach (int item in items.Keys)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("\t\t[{0}] =>", item);
         leaves = items[item];
      for (int i = 0; i < leaves.Count; i += 1) {
         Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t[{0}] => ({1})", i, leaves[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

[See this working at DotNetFiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zsmvCt)

This produces the output:

```
Type => {1}
    Items =>
        [56] =>
            [0] => (17)
            [1] => (20)
            [2] => (13)
            [3] => (14)
        [895] =>
            [0] => (11)
            [1] => (20)
        [3] =>
            [0] => (8)
            [1] => (12)
            [2] => (3)
        [19] =>
            [0] => (1)
            [1] => (2)
            [2] => (13)
            [3] => (7)
            [4] => (6)
```

Here's a run-down of how it works:

1. Split all the numbers on the closing mark (curly brace, square bracket, or parenthesis). This creates an array like `{ "{1", "[56", "(17", ... "(6", "" }`.
2. Create a variable for each level of the data structures that represents the last object at that depth of the hierarchy.
3. Quit early if we're on the last, blank, token.
4. Iterate over the split-out tokens and save the opening mark that represents the data structure hierarchy level into `symbol` and the the numerical value into `value`.
5. For each symbol, take the appropriate action.

Huge note: this code **strongly expects** the input string to be well-formed. If, for example, you passed in the string `"{1}(17)"` everything would blow up because no intermediate `[56]` was present to populate the `leaves` variable with `new List<int>` that the `(` code expects to be instantiated already.